# Use Grunt on ASP.NET MVC 5 Project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC 5 project in Visual Studio 2013 that I would like to migrate to Visual Studio 2015 so I can take advantage of VS 2015's support for Grunt.  The project opens fine in VS 2015 and I can add a gruntfile.js to the project, but the task runner doesn't work.  I assume there is additional configuration needed to make VS 2015 aware that my project is ready for Grunt, but I am not sure where that configuration resides.  Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

- Got to View menu, Other Windows, Task Runner Explorer.
- Press the Refresh button in the Task Runner Explorer and make sure your tasks appear.
- Right-click the desired task and select Run.

I got started with Stephen Walther's article here:

[ASP.NET 5 and AngularJS Part 1, Configuring Grunt, Uglify, and AngularJS](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/01/12/asp-net-5-and-angularjs-part-1-configuring-grunt-uglify-and-angularjs)

Comment: I am starting from an ASP.NET 4.5/MVC 5 website, so it's different than the article you linked to.  I manually added a gruntfile.js to the root folder of my project but when I open the Task Runner Explorer it says "Failed to load" and the Output window reads "Failed to run 'C:\path\to\gruntfile.js' ..."

Comment: @JohnCraft Scott Hanselman did another article here that may be more suitable but I never tried this one: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx Let me know if it's any good and I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a package.json and add grunt in the devDependencies so NPM can download it for you. See:
http://www.shellmonger.com/?m=201502